# How to display pages in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I just started learning magento. i found a sample helloworld module code here:

http://www.engineer-ing.com/writing-magento-extension-part1/part2

The controller code here i used is:

```
 //app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php
class Magentotutorial_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        echo 'Hello Index!';
    }
```

config.xml code:

```
//app/code/local/Magentotutorial/Helloworld/etc/config.xml
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magentotutorial_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentotutorial_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>  
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                      <file>helloworld.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
        </layout>
     </frontend>
</config>
```

helloworld.xml code

```
//app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/helloworld.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <helloworld_index_index>
            <default>
                <reference name="content">
                     <block type="page/html" name="helloworld" output="toHtml" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/>
                </reference>
            </default>
        </helloworld_index_index>
    </layout>
```

HelloWorld.php

```
class Magentotutorial_HelloWorld_Block_HelloWorld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  public function getContent()
     {
         return ‘informations about my block !!’ ;
     }
}
```

in helloworld.phtml i just type a string like "hello world to all of u".

It is not showing me any error. However nothing gets displayed on the page.

I dont know where am i doing wrong.Can someone help me to solve the problem displaying the page

Comment: Add these two lines to your .htaccess file: `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` and `php_flag display_errors 1`

Comment: The link to the tutorial is 404. You don't use the block from HelloWorld.php, do you? In this code part, you have "wordpress style apostrophes" (because of C&P?). Replace them with normal '. Maybe this is one part of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your error in layout XML. you no need `<default>` node see below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <helloworld_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
             <block type="page/html" name="helloworld" output="toHtml" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </helloworld_index_index>
</layout>
```

about block, I'm not sure that your construction will be working, if not, try to replace it to:

```
<block type="core/template" name="helloworld" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/>
```

and you forgot declare blocks in config.xml, see below:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <helloworld>
            <class>Magentotutorial_HelloWorld_Block</class>
        </helloworld>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

after this you can use next block declaration:

```
<block type="helloworld/helloworld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld/helloworld.phtml"/>
```

Hope this will be helpful